# Entry Layout Plugin issue with Stucture

Tags: structure, entry, publish-layout, layout-variables

In a channel, I've removed the Structure tab, but there's no way to get it back. Or at least, I'm missing it. The tab is gone, but all fields that were in it too and they're not in the Fields list.

I'm talking about 'Structure Parent Entry', 'Structure Page URL', 'Structure Template', 'Hide from nav' and 'Listing Channel'.

Any way of getting them back somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click 'Reset Publish Layouts" in the bottom right of the tabs panel to put it back to how it was.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, resetting was my last resort, as I don't want all my tabs I made to get messed up again. But if it's the only way, I'll just have to :) Thanks!